# .NET - MassTransit with Azure function not recieve every time

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azureservicebus, masstransit

Hi I have a question about using a topic in Azure Service Bus, which I control/configure using mass transit in my .NET application. My query is as follows, I use MassTransit to create a topic in my service and a subscription in Azure Service Bus. I then use this setup in Azure Function, where I want to respond to everything that comes from the message broker to the aforementioned topic. I don't understand why, but even if I send a completely identical message, Azure Function always catches it only on the second attempt the first one falls into the dead letter queue with the following wording. I really don't understand what's going on. Is this the right approach? Or should I trigger the function differently? However, I really don't understand why it always passes on the second time. I haven't any consumers in my app.

Application

```
            services.AddMassTransit(o =>
            {
                o.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                o.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(conString);

                    cfg.Publish<ImportDataCheckRequested>();
                    cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<ImportDataCheckRequested>("test-sub", x =>
                    {

                    });
                 
                    // I try this comment
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
```

Function

```
        [Function("Function1")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queue", "test-sub", Connection = "Test")] string myQueueItem)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message:");
        }
```

[image]

Thank you

I try send message from Azure and app too to topic. When i try send message from portal with off app it's working well so i think my problem will be in configuration app

Comment: will give you how to send the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reference** :

> I have referred this [MassTransit](https://masstransit.io/quick-starts/azure-service-bus) , git [@Chris Patterson](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/v6.3.2/src/Samples/Sample.AzureFunctions.ServiceBus) and  Stack [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713786/masstransit-endpointconvention-azure-service-bus/62714778#62714778). Thank @ChrisPatterson for the steps.

- Make sure your Azure Function is set up to activate properly.
- Review your Azure Service Bus retry and dead-letter settings. It's possible that some circumstances are causing messages to be retried or added to the dead-letter queue.
- Follow my below code

```cs
  x.UsingAzureServiceBus(configure: (context, cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.Host(connectionString: "connectionstring");
                            cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint("sampath", "sampath", e =>
                            {
                                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                            });
                            //cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

                        });
                        
                    });
                    services.AddHostedService<worker>();
```

[image]

[image]

I tried in this way hope it may be helpful to you with your requirements.

**Output** :

[image]

Comment: Excuse me , can u please tell me which MassTransient packages you utilized? I'm trying to have an azure function listening on a queue and process a MassTransit message but I got an error when I'm using `IEventReceiver _receiver`. Thanks