# Using MassTransit on an Azure Function to receive a message and process it

Tags: azure, azure-functions, masstransit

I have an Azure function that till now was receiving a classical normal formatted message that another application sent and processed it.

I've discovered MassTransit and wanted to use it in both the ASP.Net application and the Azure Function receiver. But I'm not able to set correctly in the Handler the function to decode and process the message. I've also tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76236783/net-masstransit-with-azure-function-not-recieve-every-time) but it doesn't seem to to work on 8.x version of MassTransit.

Here's my registration file and the handler

Handler

```
public class MessageReceiverHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<MessageReceiverHandler> _logger;
    private readonly IKlaviyoNameFormSender _klaviyoNameFormSender;
    private readonly IConsumer<MyOrderItemFormFilledPayload> _consumer;
    public MessageReceiverHandler(ILogger<MessageReceiverHandler> logger, IKlaviyoNameFormSender klaviyoNameFormSender, IConsumer<MyOrderItemFormFilledPayload> consumer)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _klaviyoNameFormSender = klaviyoNameFormSender;
        _consumer = consumer;
    }

    [Function(nameof(MessageReceiverHandler))]
    public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("sbq-klaviyo-orderitem-filled-form", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
        _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);

      
        var orderItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageBody>(message.Body.ToString());
        await _klaviyoNameFormSender.SendKlaviyoNameFormSender(orderItem.OrderItemId, default);

        await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Registration

```
public static IHostBuilder RegisterServices(this IHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddScoped<IKlaviyoNameFormSender, KlaviyoNameFormSender>();
        services.AddScoped<ITTGLinq2DbRepository, TTGLinq2DbRepository>();

        services.Configure<AzureServiceBusSettings>(context.Configuration.GetSection("AzureServiceBusSettings"));
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<KlaviyoOption>(opt =>
        {
[...omiss...]
        });

        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<KlaviyoNameCollectionMessageConsumer>();
            x.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
                {
                    var settings = ctx.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AzureServiceBusSettings>>().Value;

                    cfg.Host(settings.ConnectionString);

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(settings.QueueName, e =>
                    {
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<KlaviyoNameCollectionMessageConsumer>(ctx);
                    });
                });
        });
    });
    return builder;
}
```

Consumer

```
 public class KlaviyoNameCollectionMessageConsumer
     : IConsumer<KlaviyoOrderItemFormFilledPayload>
 {
     public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<KlaviyoOrderItemFormFilledPayload> context)
     {
         return;
         //TO IMPLEMENT
     }
 }

 public class KlaviyoOrderItemFormFilledPayload
 {
     public int  OrderItemId { get; set; }
 }
```

Can someone explain to me how to do that? I've read that it should be best to have an app service that runs with a background service listening on the queue, but we have a defined schema with all AzureFunction and I would like to keep the same behavior.

Comment: [Documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/azure-functions) which also includes a link to the sample.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson you use eventhub in the example but aim using service bus. And for the scendere, im fine .I don't see how can I process a ServiceBusReceivedMessage message

Comment: [It uses service bus](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureFunction/blob/master/src/Sample.AzureFunction/SubmitOrderFunctions.cs#L23) as well for the initial message.

Comment: Hello @ChrisPatterson, your example uses MassTransit.WebJobs.ServiceBus, is there a way to avoid installing webjobs in an azure function?

Comment: Have you even looked at the Azure Function dependencies? They're all built around web jobs...

Comment: OK probably that's my ignorance, I thought that Azure Function with WenJob was the old version ... since for example I've always used [Function] and not [FunctionName]. Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
I create a Mass Transit Application by following the reference post you have mentioned.

command:

```
dotnet new -i MassTransit.Templates
dotnet new mtworker -n MT_servicebus
dotnet new mtconsumer -n Welcome
```

I have created a service trigger function in `.NET 8 isolated` and used the  `Worker` and `Contaracts` code in the function.

##### My Directory:

[image]

I added the service from `Mass Transit` application's `Program.cs` file to Function's `Program.cs` file.

**`Program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MassTransit;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MT_servicebus;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

            x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

            var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

            x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
            x.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
            x.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
            x.AddActivities(entryAssembly);
            x.UsingAzureServiceBus(configure: (context, config) =>
            {
                config.Host("Endpoint=sb://servicebusouteventgrid.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxxxxxxxxxx");
                config.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`Worker.cs`:**

```cs
using Contracts;
using MassTransit;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MT_servicebus
{
    public class Worker: BackgroundService
    {
        readonly IBus _bus;
        
        public Worker(IBus bus)
        {
            _bus = bus;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await _bus.Publish(new Welcome
                {
                    Name = "Vivek"
                },stoppingToken);
                await Task.Delay(1000,stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`Contracts/Welcome.cs`:**

```cs
namespace Contracts
{
    public record Welcome
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
    }
}
```

**`Function1.cs`:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp10
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("welcome", Connection = "conn")]
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

            // Complete the message
            await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

### `OUTPUT`:

```
Functions:

        Function1: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-13T11:31:01.985Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000116B5F66'.
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.493Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=79c28ced-01a0-4e5f-b8b0-7c26c997eb84)
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.497Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 303d00007a6fb022aa1f08dc43510f5d, SequenceNumber: 1039, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-03-13T11:31:07.1550000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-03-13T11:36:07.1550000+00:00, SessionId: (null)
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.664Z] Message ID: 303d00007a6fb022aa1f08dc43510f5d
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.664Z] Message Content-Type: application/vnd.masstransit+json
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.664Z] Message Body: {
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.668Z]   "messageId": "303d0000-7a6f-b022-aa1f-08dc43510f5d",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.669Z]   "requestId": null,
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.670Z]   "correlationId": null,
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.671Z]   "conversationId": "303d0000-7a6f-b022-b9fc-08dc43510f60",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.672Z] Start processing HTTP request POST http://127.0.0.1:64397/Settlement/Complete
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.672Z]   "initiatorId": null,
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.673Z] Sending HTTP request POST http://127.0.0.1:64397/Settlement/Complete
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.673Z]   "sourceAddress": "sb://servicebusouteventgrid.servicebus.windows.net/REDACTED_FunctionApp10_bus_gy6oyyd4p6anrc8cbdqrgwecbx?autodelete=300",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.676Z]   "destinationAddress": "sb://servicebusouteventgrid.servicebus.windows.net/Contracts/Welcome?type=topic",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.677Z]   "responseAddress": null,
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.678Z]   "faultAddress": null,
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.679Z]   "messageType": [
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.680Z]     "urn:message:Contracts:Welcome"
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.681Z]   ],
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.682Z]   "message": {
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.682Z]     "name": "Vivek"
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.683Z]   },
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.684Z]   "expirationTime": null,
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.684Z]   "sentTime": "2024-03-13T11:31:00.8976415Z",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.685Z]   "headers": {},
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.686Z]   "host": {
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.686Z]     "machineName": "REDACTED",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.687Z]     "processName": "FunctionApp10",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.688Z]     "processId": 15664,
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.689Z]     "assembly": "FunctionApp10",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.689Z]     "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.691Z]     "frameworkVersion": "8.0.3",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.692Z]     "massTransitVersion": "8.1.3.0",
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.693Z]     "operatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22631.0"
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.694Z]   }
[2024-03-13T11:31:06.695Z] }
[2024-03-13T11:31:07.083Z] Received HTTP response headers after 403.8996ms - 200
[2024-03-13T11:31:07.084Z] End processing HTTP request after 416.4544ms - 200
[2024-03-13T11:31:07.130Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=79c28ced-01a0-4e5f-b8b0-7c26c997eb84, Duration=676ms)
```

[image]

Comment: but this is an azure function which has a background worker on it... I don't know if it's correct to have such a behavior with Azure Funcs

Comment: @advapi you want to run worker seperately you can do that too. As per the document you shared you can create a MassTransit console application which will send message to service bus which will trigger azure function.