# MassTransit consumer not consuming message from Azure service bus

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, masstransit, consumer

I have written a `MassTransit` consumer to consume a message from `Azure Service Bus` queue.

The consumer currently failing to consumer message from queue. I have set a breakpoint within Consumer.cs on `Consume` Task and it never hits the breakpoint?

I am not sure if I am missing anything in Program.cs in terms of configuration?

The configuration within `Program.cs` is as follows

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.AddConsumer<TestConsumer>();
                    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                    {

                        cfg.Host("sb://<endpoint>.servicebus.windows.net");

                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("<queue>", ec =>
                        {
                            ec.ConfigureConsumer<TestConsumer>(context);
                        });
                    });

                });
            });
```

Consumer.cs

```
public class TestConsumer :
    IConsumer<ConsumerData>
{
    readonly ILogger<TestConsumer> _logger;

    public TestConsumer(ILogger<TestConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ConsumerData> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hello {Username}", context.Message.User);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: [check the logs](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/integrations/logging)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson found the issue after enabling logs :)

Answer (score 1):

**Reference:**

> I have referred this [MassTransit](https://masstransit.io/quick-starts/azure-service-bus) , git [@Chris Patterson](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/v6.3.2/src/Samples/Sample.AzureFunctions.ServiceBus) and Stack [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713786/masstransit-endpointconvention-azure-service-bus/62714778#62714778). Thank @ChrisPatterson for the [steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8marp1oyY_I).

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
          Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
              {
                  services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                  {
                      x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                    x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();
                    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
                      x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
                      x.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
                      x.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
                      x.AddActivities(entryAssembly);
                      x.UsingAzureServiceBus(configure:(context,cfg)=>
                      {
                          cfg.Host("connectionstring"); // Replace with your actual connection string

                          cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queuenname", e =>
                          {
                              e.Consumer<HelloConsumer>(context); // Register your consumer for the message
                          });
                      });
                  });

                  services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
              });
  }
}
```

[image]

**In Azure :**

[image]

[image]

[image]