# Masstransit: difference between GetPublishSendEndpoint and GetSendEndpoint

Tags: c#, masstransit

What is the difference between: calling the generic `GetPublishSendEndpoint()` and providing a type for the message being sent and calling the `GetSendEndpoint()` and providing a URI parameter?

When would you use one over another?

To my understanding Sending (to a queue) and publishing (to an exchange) are two very different operations, so the idea of a PublishSend endpoint is confusing to me, and the documentation doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using RabbitMQ, if you use MassTransit's default routing, you can almost always use publish 100% of the time. As in, just call `Publish<T>`. I follow this advice almost 100% of the time, and with good reason. It's meant to make it easy and avoids the need to configure send addresses because "OMG commands have to be sent." That's nonsense, and I talk about it in several videos.

My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713786/masstransit-endpointconvention-azure-service-bus/62714778#62714778) on this subject is also relevant, stop trying to build routing around a framework that already has routing.

> And `GetPublishSendEndpoint<T>` is really just an internal methods used by `Publish<T>`, which should make sense as it is on `IPublishEndpoint` (and not `ISendEndpointProvider`).

Also, you should be using one of those two interfaces in consumer dependencies, whereas in the consumer you should always use `ConsumeContext`, to produce messages.

In summary:

1. In a consumer, using `ConsumeContext` to produce messages (publish, send, respond)
2. In a consumer dependency, using `IPublishEndpoint` or `ISendEndpointProvider`.
3. Outside of a consumer, use `IPublishEndpoint` or `ISendEndpointProvider` whenever possible.
4. Last resort, and I mean the absolute last resort, use `IBus`.

This is also [outlined in the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/producers).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy and thorough response. Is there any legitimate case for direct use for GetPublishSendEndpoint, and if not, why is it a public method?